# linux - file copy compete notificaion

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm using ssh to copy a large file from my web server to my local machine.  How can I be notified when it is done downloading?  I would ideally like to run mpg123 to play a short audio clip upon completion of file download.

Comment: If ssh cannot do this, is there a program that can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional sequence of commands:

```
scp .... && mpg123 success.mp3 || mpg123 failed.mp3
```

You may wrap this also into a bash function:

```
function fancySCP() {
   scp "${@}" && mpg123 success.mp3 || mpg123 failed.mp3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put these two commands in a script and your ssh commands in ssh_script
! when ssh finishes it will run the next command, in this case echoing 3 alarm beeps (making the pc beep)

ssh root@Otherpc 'bash -s' < ssh_script.sh

echo -e "\a\a\a"